# Translate Texts using ajax and google translate API

Tags: ajax, api, google-translate

I wanted to execute this function and make an ajax call when I click in a button in my html, but seems that the API Url is deprecated because I get an error in my console : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'translatedText' of null

ANY IDEA? Thanks

This is my javascript function:

```
function translateCaption() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
        q: 'Hello world!',  // text to translate
        v: '1.0',
        langpair: 'en|es'
    },   // '|es' for auto-detect
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result.responseData.translatedText);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, errorMsg, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorMsg);
    }
});
}
```

And this is my html:

```
<button onclick="translateCaption()" class="button-translate" type="button">Translate</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

For now is not possible to resolve only with front-end solution.
The response of your code (can see in request response in browser) is: /* callback */jQuery22108465697200462694_1552511749760({"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "Please use Translate v2.  See http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html", "responseStatus": 403})

I suggest to see https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text have examples in different programing languages (for back-end) with references to GitHub.